# Initialization error trying to install elpy for emacs

Tags: installation, emacs, package, initialization, elpy

Evening,

I'm trying to install a package for emacs having never done so before. I am using the following guide https://realpython.com/emacs-the-best-python-editor/ which intends to install elpy.

The following information is placed in `~/.emacs.d/init.el`

`;; .emacs.d/init.el
 2
 3;; ===================================
 4;; MELPA Package Support
 5;; ===================================
 6;; Enables basic packaging support
 7(require 'package)
 8
 9;; Adds the Melpa archive to the list of available repositories
10(add-to-list 'package-archives
11             '("melpa" . "http://melpa.org/packages/") t)
12
13;; Initializes the package infrastructure
14(package-initialize)
15
16;; If there are no archived package contents, refresh them
17(when (not package-archive-contents)
18  (package-refresh-contents))
;; Installs packages
21;;
22;; myPackages contains a list of package names
23(defvar myPackages
24  '(better-defaults
      elpy                            ;; Set up some better Emacs defaults
25    material-theme                  ;; Theme
26    )
27  )
28
29;; Scans the list in myPackages
30;; If the package listed is not already installed, install it
31(mapc #'(lambda (package)
32          (unless (package-installed-p package)
33            (package-install package)))
34      myPackages)
;; ===================================
37;; Basic Customization
38;; ===================================
39
40(setq inhibit-startup-message t)    ;; Hide the startup message
41(load-theme 'material t)            ;; Load material theme
42(global-linum-mode t)               ;; Enable line numbers globally
43;; ====================================
46;; Development Setup
47;; ====================================
48;; Enable elpy
49(elpy-enable)
50
51;; User-Defined init.el ends here`

However, this I pumped out in emacs when I load after saving.

`Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading ‘/Users/jay/.emacs.d/init.el’:
Symbol's function definition is void: t`

Has anyone run into this issue before? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in some code you're evaluating (e.g. code you're loading), you are trying to invoke `t` as a function.

It's likely that you meant to quote a list whose car is `t`: `'(t ...)`, and you forgot the quote mark: `(t ...)`.

Lisp tries to interpret and unquoted list as a function call, with the function being the car of the list.

I don't see such an unquoted list in the code you show. Perhaps its in some code that that code loads. To find the problem, bisect your init file. You can use command `comment-region` to comment (and with `C-u` uncomment) a region of code.